# API MISUSE(APPLE) Argument to 'NSMutableArray' method 'addObject:' cannot be nil

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, ios5, ios8

I am getting a warning when run an analyse in xcode in my app.

> Argument to 'NSMutableArray' method 'addObject:' cannot be nil.

I am getting the error when I try to add an object to an array. Where am I going wrong?

```
while(sqlite3_step(statement) == SQLITE_ROW)
{
NSLog(@"sqlite3_step");
imageUrlField = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement, 0))?
[NSString  stringWithUTF8String
(char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,0)]:
nil;

 imageTitleField = ((char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,1)) ?
 [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
 (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,1)] :
 nil;

 lat = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,2)) ?
  [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
  (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,2)] :
  nil;

 lon = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,3)) ?
 [NSString stringWithUTF8String:  
 (char*)sqlite3_column_text(statement,3)]:
 nil;

 id1 = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,4)) ?
 [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
 (char   *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,4)] :
            nil;

 visited = ((char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,5)) ?
 [NSString stringWithUTF8String:
  (char *)sqlite3_column_text(statement,5)] :
            nil;
            if(imageUrlField == nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"null");

            } else
            {
                [imageAndTitleArray addObject:imageUrlField];
                [imageAndTitleArray addObject:imageTitleField];
                [imageAndTitleArray addObject:lat];
                [imageAndTitleArray addObject:lon];
                [imageAndTitleArray addObject:id1];
                [imageAndTitleArray addObject:visited];

              // NSLog(@"url:%@",imageUrlField);
             //  NSLog(@"title:%@",imageTitleField);
            //  NSLog(@"lat:%@",lat);
             //  NSLog(@"lon:%@",lon);
             //  NSLog(@"lon:%@",id1);
            }

        }
```

Comment: there are meny values can be `nil`, according to your code... I would replace the `[... addObject:<value>];` pattern with `[... addObject:<value>?:@""];` as you'd put string anyway into the array, so like e.g. a `[imageAndTitleArray addObject:lat?:@""];`

Answer (score 1):

You can not add nil in an `NSMutableArray`, so in case your string instances are nil and you are trying to add them in `NSMutableArray`, you will get the above error of API Misuse `(API MISUSE(APPLE) Argument to 'NSMutableArray' method 'addObject:' cannot be nil)`.

You should check if the string is not nil before adding it to the

```
NSMutableArray as

if(imageUrlField != nil)
                [imageAndTitleArray addObject:imageUrlField];

if(imageTitleField != nil)
                [imageAndTitleArray addObject:imageTitleField];

if(lat != nil)
                [imageAndTitleArray addObject:lat];

//like so for others

if(visited != nil)
                [imageAndTitleArray addObject:visited];
```

If for any case you need to add `null` in `NSMutableArray` than you can use `[array addObject:[NSNull null]];`